# Position and size are ambiguous for NSVisualEffectView

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have a vague, and frustrating, auto-layout problem. This occurs in an `NSPanel` that contains a few buttons, fields, and an `NSTableView`. The cells of the table view are fairly complex, consisting of several nested `NSStackView`s, but when loaded everything appears the way it is supposed to.

Except, for two text fields that are aligned to the scroll view. They do not have the correct height, width, or alignment (although they appear just fine in IB).

[image]

IB doesn't report any layout issues with the views. At runtime, the Debug View Hierarchy tool reports a single warning: "Position and size are ambiguous for NSVisualEffectView".

[image: View hierarchy with layout error]

My problem is that the `NSVisualEffectView` object has no constraints. I tried following the steps in [Detecting Ambiguous Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AmbiguousLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH18-SW1) and get nowhere:

- sending `hasAmbiguousLayout` returns YES
- sending `exerciseAmbiguityInLayout` doesn't appear to do anything
- sending `constraintsAffectingLayoutForOrientation:` returns empty arrays for both orientations

I've read elsewhere that nesting `NSStackView`s can create ambiguous layouts, but I have no clue as to how to address that.

Has anyone encountered this or have a suggestion on how to proceed?

Note that I've tried various alternatives to the layout of the text fields, including aligning them to the superview instead of the table view, using high and low values for compression resistance, hugging, etc. It doesn't matter, I still the get `NSVisualEffectView` warning and they are not positioned correctly.

Comment: Hi, James! You're certainly doing everything right: a mispositioned (or missing) view is often an indication of ambiguous layout, and your use of the view debugger and `hasAmbiguousLayout` confirms it. You should theoretically be able to track this down in the view debugger, which tells you all about the constraints on every view — though it sounds like your view doesn't have _any_ constraints. I'm afraid the question doesn't give enough information to say more, and it's hard for you to _give_ more info, I know.

Comment: Update: I reworked the cell views so they do not use nested `NSStackView`s, but the problem remains, so it doesn't look like nested stack views is the issue.

Comment: Could it be that there's a use of NSVisualEffectView that isn't what it's for? Can you manage without it? What's its purpose?

Comment: @matt I don't add `NSVisualEffectView`, it's something that's added automatically by Cocoa. From the documentation: "AppKit creates visual effect views automatically for window titlebars, popovers, and source list table views. You don't need to add visual effect views to those elements of your interface."

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it's a red herring. Perhaps "My problem is that the NSVisualEffectView object has no constraints" is misleading. If the visible issue is the text fields perhaps we need to concentrate on their constraints instead.

Comment: The text field reports that's position is *not* ambiguous, and all of its  constraints (which consists of just 2 to position it, plus its content size) are all valid, but they clearly are not. For example, it's a simple one-line label (small label size), yet it's content constraint claims it's 42px high. It's like the layout engine got to the `NSVisualEffectsView` and then just gave up.